# custom propertyConverter in filter is getting overridden in Neo4j OGM

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, sdn, neo4j-ogm

I am manually setting propertyConverter of a filter in Neo4j OGM.

```
filter.setPropertyConverter(new EnumArrayStringConverter(VendorCostStatus.class));
filters.add(filter);
```

But then when I call session.loadAll(DomainClass.**class**, filters), it is picked by `LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(Class<T> type, Filters filters)`

But then LoadByTypeDelegate overrides the propertyConverter of the filter by calling

`resolvePropertyAnnotations(Class entityType, Iterable<Filter> filters)`

and sets the default converter of the property in the domain class.

Could anyone please tell me how to make neo4j-ogm use the custom property converter provided in the filter? I want to use `ComparisonOperator.IN` for enum attributes

Answer (score 0):

Setting your own property converter is deprecated, and anyway, I believe it was never built with that intention. It seems to be an api that should not have been exposed but was at the time.