# Spring Neo4j: How to use Enums with Filters

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, sdn, neo4j-ogm

I want to use `ComparisonOperator.IN` with Enum property in Filters. But **neo4j-ogm** is converting the comma-separated string provided as a value in Filters to Enum string and failing with exception unable to convert to enum class. Could anyone suggest how to resolve this?

**EDIT 1:**

```
Filter filter = new Filter("myEnumField", ComparisonOperator.IN, new ArrayList<MyEnum>(enum1, enum2));
filter.setBooleanOperator(BooleanOperator.AND);
```

Comment: Could you provide a small example of how you are doing this and what is the expectation?

Answer (score 0):

This is either not supported or a bug. The type of the property is used in the converter, not the type of the parameter.

A workaround to this would be to compose a custom query instead using Filters.

Comment: Also @Luanne Could you please check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625855/custom-propertyconverter-in-filter-is-getting-overridden-in-neo4j-ogm

Comment: Setting your own property converter is deprecated, and anyway, it was never built with that intention. It seems to be an api that should not have been exposed but was. Please accept the answer if the above approach works for you, thanks!